# codesign requires keychain password even after 'security unlock-keychain'

Tags: xcode, code-signing, keychain

I'm running xcodebuild in a script to archive and export my project. I'm code signing using a keychain file.
In order to avoid the prompt to enter the keychain password, I'm using

```
security unlock-keychain -p <Password> <Keychain file>
```

This command finishes successfully without any output

Still, when I run xcodebuild, I'm getting prompted with

> codesign wants to use the "myKeychain" keychain.

What am I missing? I'm running xcode 9.4.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the I issued the `unlock-keychain` before the build, and the signing was happening like 45 minutes later. The unlocking expired.

This can be solved with

```
security set-keychain-settings -lut 7200 <keychain>
```

I solved it by issuing the unlock command right before the signing